# Best way to prevent duplicate values based on another value SQL

Tags: mysql, constraints, duplicates, duplicate-data

I am looking for the best way to prevent duplicate data in a table that is based on another data point.

Table: (a joining table between two entities, person and school)

`CREATE TABLE with_school (
  person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  school_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  type_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (person_id,school_id)
);`

`person_id` and `school_id` are also foreign keys, declared in a different statement.

What I want is something that prevents a person from adding the same school more than once.

Examples:

Row 1:

`person_id = 1
school_id = 1`

Row 2:

`person_id = 1
school_id = 2`

is okay, but:

Row 1:

`person_id = 1
school_id = 1`

Row 2:

`person_id = 1
school_id = 1`

is not.

What would be the easiest way to prevent these kinds of duplicates?

I have tried using a trigger, but I haven't been able to make it work the way I want it to:

`ALTER TABLE with_school
ADD CHECK (
  school_id != (
    SELECT school_id 
    FROM with_school 
    WHERE person_id = person_id
  )
);`
(I cannot differentiate between the initial person_id and the one it is checking)

Comment: just add a unique key on those fields. ``alter table with_school add unique key `id_restrictions` (person_id, school_id)``. Now you can only ever have ONE record with `(1,1)` as its value, yet still allow `(1,2)` and `(2,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating uniqueness at the database level....like:

`ALTER TABLE with_school ADD UNIQUE uniqueindex (person_id, school_id);`

And...probably in addition....you could do an sql select 'check' at the application level before inserting to make sure you don't already have those two keys.